# Update owned entity EF Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am implementing an api using .net 5.
I have a student class which have a property with address type(value object according to ddd).

```
public class Student 
{
        public long Id{ get; private set; }
        public string FirstName { get; private set; }
        public string LastName { get; private set; }
        public Address Address { get; private set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; private set; }
    public string Road { get; private set; }
}
```

I am using fluent api to configure the database using ef core 5.

```
 class StudentConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
    {

        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Students");
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

            builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever().IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasMaxLength(25).IsRequired();
            builder.Property(x => x.LastName).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();           


            builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Address, x =>
            {
                x.Property(pp => pp.City)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("City")
                    .HasMaxLength(20);
                x.Property(pp => pp.Road)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("Road")
                    .HasMaxLength(40);
            });

        }
    }
```

As a result I have one table with columns Id,Fistname,lastname,city,road.

Now I am trying to update only the city and the road(for example a student change house)
but I have different exceptions and I don't know how to update only these 2 columns

```
public async Task UpdateAddress(Student student)
{
//Firts try 
            //var studentEntry = context.Entry(student);
            //studentEntry.Property(x => x.Address.City).IsModified = true;
            //studentEntry.Property(x => x.Address.Road).IsModified = true;
            //**Exception** 'The expression 'x => x.Address.City' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')'

//Second try 
             //var studentEntry = context.Entry(student.Address);
            //studentEntry.Property(x => x.City).IsModified = true;
            //studentEntry.Property(x => x.Road).IsModified = true;
            //**Exception** 'Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. 

//the only method that works is Update but this update the whole object
     context.Update(student);
     await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

EDIT

```
public class StudentDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

How can update only these two properties of an owned entity?

Comment: Could you show you full dbcontext pls?

Comment: @Sergey Edited and add dbcontext

Comment: the problem is i have private set using a domain driven design approach , only in mya address domain i can change this values, not outside, as a result i fet an error when i try to set the values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Address` is [owned entity type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities), hence `Student.Address` property by EF Core terminology is not a *property*, but *reference navigation property*, thus should be accessed via [`Reference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1.reference?view=efcore-5.0) method rather than [`Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry-1.property?view=efcore-5.0) method (none of them supports property path). Then you can use the returned tracking entry to access its members.

To force updating just some properties of the `Student.Address`, first attach the `Student` entity instance (to tell EF that it is existing)

```
var studentEntry = context.Attach(student);
```

and then use something like this

```
var addressEntry = studentEntry.Reference(e => e.Address);
addressEntry.TargetEntry.Property(e => e.City).IsModified = true;
addressEntry.TargetEntry.Property(e => e.Road).IsModified = true;
```

Comment: How can I update entire reference? I'm unable to save my owned property if all fields in db are NULL.

Comment: @erikscandola What EF Core version are you targeting? There were some changes related to what they call optional/required dependents, especially for owned types.

Comment: ef core can handle this in the current version (ef core 6+). You need to track the entity before the changes are made - then the change tracker can detect the changes and update them accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Since your queries are not tracked by EntityFramework (because you set that in your DBContext configuration) you can try the following flow:

Firstly get student from DB by its ID and then change only those two properties you want to change on that entity directly.

```
public async Task UpdateAddress(Student student)
{
    // Get existing student by its ID from the database
    var existingStudent = await context.Students
        .Include(x => x.Address)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == student.Id);

    // To prevent null reference exception
    if (existingStudent is null)
        return; // Exception maybe? Depends on your app flow

    // Edit address value object with the method available in your entity, since you're using DDD approach
    existingStudent.ChangeAddress(student.Address);

    // Since your query are not tracked you need to explicity tell EF that this entry is being modified
    context.Entry(existingStudent).State = EntityState.Modified;

    // EF will save only two properties in that case
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Than in your `Student` entity class add the following method to provide ability to change its address:

```
public void ChangeAddress(Address newAddress)
{
    // Some additional conditions to check the newAddress for nulls, valid values, etc.

    Address = newAddress;
}
```

You can treat your Address as a ValueObject and replace it with the new Address VO.

Comment: It is a copy of the previous answer.

Comment: Oh, didn't really see that when I was creating this one. I explained step by step the whole flow to better understand the concept of that code and the idea from where it came from.

Comment: I am sorry but it seems to me that  a post owner  has enough experience to understand my code without any extra explanations.